# “Gutter” or fixed width column with minimal margin/padding

Tags: bootstrap-4

I have the following layout (I’ve removed classes that don’t relate to layout):

```
<li class="row">
  <div class="col order-0 col-md-1 time">
   <div class="d-flex">
     <div class="mr-3" style="background: DeepPink"></div>
     23:23
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-12 order-2 order-md-1 col-md-10">
    Comment...  
  </div>
  <p class="col order-md-2 col-md-1 menu-column text-right text-md-center">
    <a href="#">Edit</a>
  </p>
</li>
```

Here’s an example of what it looks like on a mobile device:

[image: Mobile Layout]

And here’s the same thing (full width) for a desktop:

[image: Desktop Layout]

I’d like the coloured bar to be in it’s own column - so that it will extend over the height of the content. Basically, a fixed width column that will act as a “gutter” (with minimal margin/padding).

Is this sort of thing possible using a Bootstrap 4 grid? Or would I be better off implementing my own flex layout? In the case of the latter, I’m not sure how to create the same thing using `d-flex`. Any pointers would be helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Here’s what I’ve come up with so far:

```
<li class="row">
  <div class="mr-3" style="background: DeepPink" style="flex: 0 0 4px; max-width: 4px”>&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="w-100 mw-100 row">
    <div class="col order-0 col-md-1 time">
      23:23
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 order-2 order-md-1 col-md-10">
      Comment...  
    </div>
    <div class="col order-md-2 col-md-1 menu-column text-right text-md-center">
      <a href="#">Edit</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</li>
```

The first nested `div` just relies on flex layout. However, I did have to add the `&nbsp;` - if the `div` was empty and the comments wrapped several lines, then the coloured bar would look “squashed” (reduced in width).

In the second nested `div`, I ended up using `w-100 mw-100` instead of `col-12` to avoid grid padding/margin. The solution isn’t perfect, but it provides a good starting point for now.